# Substituir uso de dataframe com pandas .apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas, dataframe

Eu possuo uma função que itera uma planilha, que faz alguns controles. Procurei sobre e vi sobre o .apply, mas não consegui implentar. Gostaria de saber se conseguiria nesse caso, substituir o uso que faço e por questão de performance, alterar para o .apply.

No caso, possuo um dicionário que ele consulta para minhas condições tratadas. E a função que itera fazendo um laço pra que isso ocorra. A função depende do cargo que eu passo no dicionário e que vem da planilha para saber se exibe um campo de foto ou não.

```
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['cargo'] in cargos_to_display_photo:
            df.loc[i, 'display_foto'] = True
        else:
            df.loc[i, 'display_foto'] = False
    return df
```

a função que "prepara" o data frame é:

```
def prepare_dataframe(df_google):
    df_google = set_display_photo(df_google)
    return df_google
```

o dicionário:

```
cargos_to_display_photo = [
    'Trainee | Assessoria de Investimentos',
    'Sócio Fundador',
    'Superintendente',
    'Assessor de Investimentos',
    'Sócia | Assessor de Investimentos',
    'Líder Corporate',
    'Trainee | Corporate',
]
```

a coluna que consulto:

```
columns_dict = {
    'SEXO' : 'sexo',
    'CÓDIGO' : 'codigo',
    'Nome Completo' : 'nome',
    'Cidade' : 'unidade',
    'Cargo' : 'cargo',
}
```

As colunas que não efetuo consulta ou que não foram citadas no trecho eu descarto pelo próprio código, dando um drop nelas com as tratativas necessárias pra que não precise iterar.

das formas que pesquisei, não consegui implentar nenhuma. Não consegui fazer com que o apply populasse a planilha. Seria possível fazer isso com essas funções?

Comment: A formatação do código da sua pergunta ficou ruim, abaixo do primeiro return df você deve colocar os ``` mais pro lado esquerdo.
Outra questão, você consegue disponibilizar a planilha para testes?

Comment: ajustei, o link da mesma: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VFETvsNvA-NCFPlplCtZ1qPw3HeaCV7Te2x8kopf7ZE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @lmonferrari eu tirei alguns campos da planilha porque possui alguns dados confidenciais. Mas acredito que dê pra você testar.

Comment: Claro, sem problemas!

Answer (score 1):

> Procurei sobre e vi sobre o .apply, mas não consegui implementar. Gostaria de saber se conseguiria nesse caso, substituir o uso que faço e por questão de performance, alterar para o .apply.

Importando o arquivo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./Cadastro Colaboradores BT.xlsx')
```

Lista com os cargos:

```
cargos_to_display_photo = [ 'Trainee | Assessoria de Investimentos', 
                           'Sócio Fundador', 'Superintendente', 
                           'Assessor de Investimentos', 
                           'Sócia | Assessor de Investimentos', 
                           'Líder Corporate', 'Trainee | Corporate', ]
```

Código com o apply:

```
df['display_foto'] = df['Cargo'].apply(lambda x: x in cargos_to_display_photo)
```

Crio uma coluna chamada display_foto, aplico o apply na coluna Cargo do dataframe e faço uma função anonima que verifica se o conteúdo da coluna linha a linha.

- Tempo de execução com o laço for:

  *69.4 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)*
- Tempo de execução com apply:

  *305 µs ± 30.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)*

Comment: não consegui entender ainda. O que muda na função do display_photo?

Comment: No código que postei a função `set_display_foto` é substituída por uma função anonima `lambda`, essa função verifica dentro da sua lista de `cargos_to_display_fotos` se na coluna `cargos` existe  algum valor compatível, caso encontre o valor verdadeiro, ele retorna True, caso não encontre retorna False.  No comando `df['display_foto'] =` está sendo criado uma nova coluna chamada `display_foto` exatamente como sua função fazia.

Comment: mas essa coluna é criada na planilha? Porque eu não posso alterar ela. Não é de meu controle, eu uso ela somente pra leitura dos dados e iteração.

Comment: Não Wanderson, ela é criada no seu data frame, da mesma forma que sua função faz. Essa coluna vai aparecer somente se você criar um novo arquivo excel ou mandar salvar na planilha atual.

Comment: o df['display_foto'] = df['Cargo'].apply(lambda x: x in cargos_to_display_photo) eu chamo no prepare dataframe, no caso?

Comment: Caso você queira chamar dentro da prepare_dataframe você poderia fazer assim:
 `def prepare_dataframe(df_google):
    df_google['display_foto'] = df_google['Cargo'].apply(lambda x: x in cargos_to_display_photo)`

Comment: Caso você queira retornar um NOVO dataframe: `def prepare_dataframe(df_google):
    df_prepared = df_google
    df_prepared['display_foto'] = df_google['Cargo'].apply(lambda x: x in cargos_to_display_photo)
    return df_prepared`

Comment: legal! só não consegui testar.. Antes usava:
```
 for i, row in df_google.iterrows():
   ...:     print(row['nome'], row['cargo'], row['display_foto'])
```
no shell e ele retornava a planilha. Como você testou?

Comment: da uma olhada: https://ibb.co/Jm4Dw50 
removi os nomes da imagem mas ai está como eu faço

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria usando a função [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) do pandas. Ela retorna uma lista booleana quando encontra algum valor dentro do array **cargos_to_display_photo**

```
df['display_foto'] = df['Cargo'].isin(cargos_to_display_photo)
df.head()
    SEXO    CÓDIGO  Nome completo   Cidade      Cargo       display_foto
0   m       NaN     Samuel...       Ribeir...   Sócio ...   False
1   m       NaN     Leonar...       Uberlâ...   Assess...   True
2   m       NaN     Andre ...       Franca      Sócio ...   False
3   f       NaN     Rejane...       Uberlâ...   Assess...   False
4   m       NaN     Wevers...       Rio de...   Traine...   True
```

Uma boa prática para se obter desempenho(velocidade) nas execuções em pandas é evitar usar loops de repetição, assim como a função [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (que também é um tipo de iteração).
Segue o tempo de execução da minha proposta:

> 220 µs ± 5.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)